# Surface Pro 7 webcam doesn't work

Tags: 22.04, webcam, surface

I'm new in Linux. I have a Surface Pro 7. I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but the integrated camera is not working.
I've tried the following commands:

"cheese"

(cheese:6557): Gdk-WARNING **: 14:22:18.917: Native Windows taller than 65535 pixels are not supported
** Message: 14:22:18.938: cheese-application.vala:222: Error during camera setup: Nessun dispositivo trovato
(cheese:6557): cheese-CRITICAL **: 14:22:18.946: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed
(cheese:6557): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:22:18.946: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
(cheese:6557): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:22:18.946: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
(cheese:6557): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:22:18.946: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
(cheese:6557): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:22:18.946: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
(cheese:6557): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:22:18.946: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given
(cheese:6557): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:22:18.946: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
** (cheese:6557): CRITICAL **: 14:22:18.946: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
(cheese:6557): Clutter-CRITICAL **: 14:22:41.898: Unable to create dummy onscreen: No foreign surface, and wl_shell unsupported by the compositor

"lsusb -v | grep Camera"
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

"lsmod | grep uvc"
no output

Thank you

Comment: Even the latest kernel does not support Surface Pro 7 camera. https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=89ab28028e Also, the Linux Surface project does not support it yet https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Supported-Devices-and-Features#feature-matrix

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I see, thanks a lot!
M.